# Why return -1 is not working as expected

Tags: sql-server, exception, procedure, raiserror

I am new to SQL Server. Please help me with this issue

```
RAISERROR('There is a problem in the code',16,1)
RETURN -1
```

This is working perfectly fine. So I put this in a common procedure like this:

```
CREATE procedure  [dbo].[Raise_Error]
    (@ErrorMsg varchar(6000) ,
     @ErrorSeverity integer = 16,
     @ErrorState integer = 1)
AS
BEGIN           
    RAISERROR (@ErrorMsg, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState)
    RETURN -1 
END
```

Now when I call this procedure from another procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TEST_ORIG
AS
BEGIN   
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM  table where FISCALYEAR='2016')
    BEGIN
        EXEC utils.dbo.[Raise_error]
             @ErrorMsg = 'There are no valid records for     processing'                             
        RETURN -1 
    END
```

I am getting an error message

> Msg 178, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
>   A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context

Can anyone throw some light on what is happening here and how can I correct it? I need to return -1 here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of returning value, it is good to use output variables and consume in the calling procedure

Comment: When you raise an error, execution stops at the `RAISE` statement. The code in your first procedure never hits the `RETURN` statement because `RAISERROR` stops execution and throws the exception. SQL Server has recognized this and is telling you you'll never see the return value, and it's right. I'd suggest getting rid of your first procedure altogether because it adds no value: it does exactly what the out-of-the-box `RAISERROR` does. Use `RAISERROR` when you have an exception. You don't need a custom procedure.

Answer (score 0):

you need use try block to catch the raiseerror

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE TEST_ORIG
    AS
    BEGIN
      BEGIN TRY   
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM  table where FISCALYEAR='2016')
        BEGIN
            EXEC utils.dbo.[Raise_error]
                 @ErrorMsg = 'There are no valid records for     processing'                             
            RETURN -1 
        END
      END TRY  
      BEGIN CATCH
           SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE()
      END CATCH
    END
```